# Proof by induction for ${m+n \choose n+r} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{m \choose k}{n \choose r+k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I've gotten as far as splitting it into two sets and I got: $${m+n+1 \choose m+r} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{m \choose k}\left({n+1 \choose r+k}\right) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{m \choose k}\left({n \choose r+k}+{n\choose r+k-1}\right)= {m+n\choose m+r}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{m\choose k}{n\choose r+k-1} $$ but I'm stuck about how to solve the final term. I also tried doing induction on *m* but got stuck in a similar place.

(I do not think that Vandermonde's identity does helps with this problem, as I am looking to solve for ${m+n \choose m+r}$ rather than ${m+n \choose r}$.)

Comment: Just to clarify, is there some difference between the meaning of $\left({n+1 \choose r+k}\right)$ and $\binom{n+1}{r+k}$? Similarly $\left(\binom n{r+k}\right)$ and $\binom n{r+k}$ in [your post on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30781/i-dont-believe-my-question-is-a-duplicate).

Comment: It seems that [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Bm%2Bn%20%5Cchoose%20n%2Br%7D%20%3D%20%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bm%7D%7Bm%20%5Cchoose%20k%7D%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20r%2Bk%7D%24&p=1) you can find a few posts that are very close to yours. For example: [Prove that $ \sum_{k=0}^m {m \choose k} {n \choose r+k} = {m+n \choose m+r}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2206456), [Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\binom{m}k\binom{n}{r+k}=\binom{m+n}{m+r}$ using combinatoric arguments.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1659106), ...

Comment: ... [Prove by Double Counting Method $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r + k} = \binom{m + n}{m + r}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2201873), [Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k} \binom{s}{n+k} = \binom{r+s}{r+n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/923032)

Comment: @JMoravitz Since the question was closed by you, I thought it might be reasonable to let you know about the OP's post on meta: [I don't believe my question is a duplicate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30781)

Comment: Since I have mentioned Approach0, I will also add link to a post with some other tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)